# How to do Lakshmi Puja in Diwali?

Tags: rituals, puja, festivals, lakshmi

What is the best way to do Lakshmi Puja in Diwali?

So how should one go with the following before starting with the puja?

- What are the things that we need to use?
- What is the actual process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Remember One thing that every worship or prayer needs your faith and The Holy Spirit
and it is the core component of a successful worship**

- Worship must be conducted with a calm frame of mind. One should be calm and the mind should be quiet while doing this worship and afterwards too.
- This is not easy, but one must try patiently and assiduously for this calm frame of mind. This is very important.
- Calmness is a result of one's confidence and faith in God.

**Worship Procedure**

Print out the two photos of [*Sundara MahaLakshmi*](https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4028/4471921145_07873e614f_z.jpg?zz=1) and her consort [*Kamala Varadaraja*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8qIk.jpg) and frame them. Click on the links below to get these photos:

1. Keep these photos in front of you at the level of your eyes when you are seated. (If you have a home shrine, that much better!)
2. It is a good idea to light a minimum of two deepa lamps and place them on either side of or in front of the deity photos. Lighting a minimum of two incense sticks and keeping them near the deities is also a good idea. If you don't know how to do this, skip to the next step.
3. Sit down in front of the photos of Sundara MahaLakshmi and lord Kamala Varadarajar. These photos should be at the level of your eyes.

Chanting following Verse

> *Ya Sa Padma Sanastha Vipula Kati Tati Padma Patrayat Aksi
>
>   Gam Bhira Vartana Bhistana Bharana Mita Subhra Vastrottariya
>
>   Ya Laksmir Divya Rupa Irmani Gana Kha Citaih Sna Pitahema Kumbh Aih
>
>   Sa Nityam Padma Hasta Mama Vasatu Grhe Sarva Mangalyayukta Swaha*

Comment: Any chance you could provide a Latin alphabet transliteration of the verse?

Answer (score 2):

> The consort of Lord Vishnu, Lakshmi is the Goddess of wealth and
>   prosperity. She bestows eight kinds of wealth. In Hindu households she
>   is the most commonly worshipped Goddess. It is believed that there
>   will not be prosperity if Goddess Lakshmi is not worshipped. Vidya
>   lakshmi bestows knowledge, Vijaya Lakshmi is associated with success,
>   Dhanya Lakshmi is for food and prosperity, Soubhagya Lakshmi for a
>   happy marriage, Dhairya Lakshmi is for courage and Santana Lakshmi is
>   worshipped for children.
>
> Goddess Lakshmi is believed to exist in various forms. The most
>   important of them are Neeladevi, Bhoodevi and Sridevi. Sridevi
>   represents movable assets and Bhoodevi is known for immoveable assets.
>   When Lord Vishnu has taken avataras or different form to save the
>   universe, Goddess Lakshmi also came in other forms to support him.
>   During Ramavatara, Ram’s wife Sita is considered to be Goddess
>   Lakshmi.
>
> Lakshmi is also known as Sri or Thirumagal as she is associated with
>   six divine and auspicious qualities. Diwali and Kojagiri Purnima are
>   celebrated in the honour of Gddess Lakshmi.
>
> **Lakshmi’s other names**
>
> Goddess Lakshmi is known with several names. Padma, Kamala,
>   Padmapriya, Padmamaladhara devi, Padmamukhi, Padmakshi, Padmahasta,
>   Padmasundari are some of them. She is worshipped with her special 1008
>   names as mentioned in the scriptures.
>
> **In praise of Lakshmi**
>
> There are several slokas which praise Mahalakshmi. Some of the most
>   popular prayers are “Sri Mahalakshmi Ashtakam”, “Lakshmi Stuti”,
>   “Kanakadhara stotram”, “Agastya Lakshmi Stotra” and “Sri Sukta”.
>
> According to Kalki Purana, when Vishnu will incarnate as Kalki,
>   Lakshmi will appear in the form of Padma and two sons will be born.
>
> Business people worship Goddess Lakshmi every day before commencing
>   the work. Thursdays and Fridays are considered auspicious for
>   worshipping Goddess Lakshmi.

[Source](http://www.pandit.com/lakshmi-pooja/)

Answer (score 0):

The rituals for performance of Lakshmi Puja on the night of Dipawali are mentioned in the Padma and Skanda Purans.

According to [**Padma Puran Uttar Khand**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc365701.html):

> **Before Viṣṇu has got up, he should awaken Lakṣmī through the women**. When a man has awakened Lakṣmī at the time of her getting up through a good woman, for one year Lakṣmī does not leave him. The haters of gods (i.e. the demons) scared of Viṣṇu obtained fearlessness from the brāhmaṇas, after knowing (that Viṣṇu) was asleep in the Milky Ocean, and Lakṣmī had resorted to the lotus.

> **“You are the lustre, Śrī Ravi (i.e. the Sun), the Moon, the Lightning, the Golden Star; the lustre occurring in the lustre of the lamp is the lustre of all the lustres. That Lakṣmī that lives on the earth, in the cowpen on the auspicious day of Dīpāvalī in Kārtika, may grant me a boon.”**

> Śiva and Bhavānī took to playing with dice as a sport. Lakṣmī, propitiated by Bhavānī remained in the form of a cow. Formerly Pārvatī vanquished Śiva in the game of dice, and sent him away naked. So this Śiva is unhappy. Gaurī always remains happy. He who gets victory first (passes) the year happily. **When the night passes like this, and people have their eyes half-closed, Alakṣmī is driven out of the courtyard of the house by the joyful city-women by means of sounding the musical instruments and drums.**

The [**Kartikmasmahatmya of the Skanda Puran**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc371650.html) tells us:

> **On the fourteenth day in the dark half of the month of Āśvina, on the new-moon day and on the first day (of Kārttika) which is in conjunction with Svāti constellation, one should take these three days as the festival days of lights.**

Further the text mentions:

> At the time of daybreak on the new-moon day, O leading sages, one should take bath and devoutly worship and bow down to Devas and Pitṭs. He should then perform the Pārvaṇa Śrāddha with curds, milk, ghee etc. None but children and sick persons should take food during the day time.

> **Then, at nightfall, he should worship the splendid Goddess Indirā (Lakṣmī). He should then erect a clean and beautiful pavilion for Lakṣmī by means of various kinds of cloths. It should be wonderfully decorated with various kinds of sprouts and flowers of various colours. There he should worship Lakṣmī as well as Devas.**

> Goddesses (such as Sarasvatī, Kālī, Gaurī) too should be worshipped with many types of offerings and services. He should devoutly massage the feet of Lakṣmī and others. Formerly it was on this day that Devas were set free from the prison of Bali. Lakṣmī too was released (therefrom). Thereafter, the Devas went to the Milk Ocean along with Lakṣmī. They slept soundly for a long time.
> **Hence, O great sages, the cots are to be made with twines within and there should be fine cotton beds. They shall be covered with excellent sheets resembling milk and foams. The devotee should install those Suras and Lakṣmī in the proper directions to the accompaniment of Vedic chants.** Freed from the fear of Daityas, Lakṣmī slept soundly within the lotus. Hence, here too, all amenities for sound sleep should be made.

> **If a person makes a bed of lotuses on that day, for increasing the happiness of Lakṣmī, she will not go anywhere else leaving his house.** If persons do not provide such amenities for the sound sleep of Lakṣmī, can those men sleep at night without being worried about money? Hence a man should worship Lakṣmī making all efforts. He should be rid of poverty and become well-established among the members of his own community.

> **Cow’s milk should be boiled along with nutmeg, cloves, cardamoms and camphor. Sugar should be added as much as is necessary. Laḍḍukas (ball-shaped sweets) shall be made thereby and dedicated to Lakṣmī.**

> **All the four types of foodstuffs also should be made and offered saying, “May Śrī be pleased.” Even before Hari wakes up, Lakṣmī should be wakened through women devotees.** If a woman or the man wakens Lakṣmī at the (proper) time and then takes food, Lakṣmī never forsakes her or him for the whole year.

> Demons became frightened of Viṣṇu. After getting shelter and immunity from fear from Brāhmaṇas they went to the Milk Ocean. After knowing that Lakṣmī who had resorted to the lotus was asleep, they eulogized her: “You are the refulgent splendour of all the luminous bodies like the sun, the moon, fire, lighting, gold and stars. You are the splendour of all luminous bodies. Obeisance, O Goddess stationed in the (bright) flame of the lamp. May that Lakṣmī who is present on the meritorious day of Dīpāvalī on the earth, and in the cowpen on the Kārttikī day be the bestower of boons to me.”

> **Thereafter the lamp should be offered in the early part of the night. A firebrand should be whirled round one’s own head. It is preventive of all calamities and misfortunes.**

> **‘Light-trees’ should be made according to one’s capacity in temples etc., quadrangles, cremation grounds, rivers, mountains, houses, roots of trees, cowpens, levelled square-shaped plots of sacrifice, etc. The grounds along highway should be decorated and beautified with cloths and flowers.**

> **After the midnight passes thus, when men are asleep with half-closed eyes, the delighted women of the city begin to drive away Alakṣmī (Ill-luck, Misfortune) from their respective courtyards with winnowing baskets and small Ḍiṇḍima drums**.

**So to summarize, the rituals to be followed are:**

**1.** An early morning bath, offering Shraadh to Pitris, feeding Brahmins and fasting yourself.

**2.** Preparing a pedestal for Goddess Lakshmi and other forms of god which should be decorated with bright clothes and flowers.

**3.** Making cots with soft cotton for the gods to sleep in especially using lotus flowers for Goddess Lakshmi.

**4.** Sweets made of cow's milk, sugar and certain aromatic spices to be offered to Lakshmi.

**5.** Women of the house to wake Lakshmi by reciting a hymn used by the Asuras in older days.

**6.** Lighting lamps and waving firebrands around oneself before lighting diyas in and around the vicinity.

**7.** Driving out of Alkashmi from the courtyards/cowpens by the women by creating noise and beating drums.